# How to determine the JAXB version used in an application

Tags: jaxb

I use JDK 1.6 and I work on an a existing application which is using JAXB.

How can I know whether I am using JAXB 1 or JAXB 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are any annotations from the `javax.xml.bind.annotation` package in your model then you are using [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222).  These annotations did not exist in [**JAXB 1 (JSR-31)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=31).  A JAXB 1 model consists of spec defined generated interfaces backed by implementation specific impl classes.

Comment: Yes  we are using Anootations and thanks a lot you are really expert in JAXB .